# How do use one channel from an image in a material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an image that is split up over the RGB channels. I only want to apply the data from the blue channel. I have made a material and a texture using nodes that separates the color but when I select the texture in the edit mode nothing happens.

I have managed to apply the image to the plane using the UV/ImageEditor but that applies all of the channels.

Comment: are you using cycles? from your question it sounds like you are quite close, good start!

Comment: No I'm not sure how that works. I thought nodes didn't work with cycles as well?

Comment: No cycles works entirely off nodes. What render engine are you using?

Comment: I was using the blender render but I just changed it to cycles. Not sure what to do next

Comment: no problem, I'm writing an answer now, just a min.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the image UV mapped to your mesh, good.

### For the cycles render engine:

First you will want to make an entirely new material. (the settings from BI could mess things up a bit)
You want your new material's nodes to look something like this.
[image: cycles material nodes]

The first two nodes are how the texture gets in to your material.
The selected ([Separate RGB](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/converter.html#separate-rgb-node)) node is where it all happens, it takes the color form your image, and splits it into the three channels (the three outputs R G B). So since you only are interested in the blue channel, just plug that output in to your shader.

---

### For the blender internal:

The process is much the same, you have to use the nodes. Here is what just the BI's material nodes look like. (This is assuming you already have the proper material and texture set up.)
[image: BI nodes]

Still just the Separate RGB node, and you are choosing what channel you want to use in the output.

Comment: Thank you that worked only my plane became a box? My end goal is to rotate it to create a sort of wheel which I can in turn spin to create a 3d like effect.