# Is there a way to save single channel OpenEXR output files in blender

Tags: .exr, depth-map

I am currently trying to save the depth using a technique under the following: [Getting the depth of every pixel to the center of projection of the camera in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238218/getting-the-depth-of-every-pixel-to-the-center-of-projection-of-the-camera-in-bl) (effectively storing the mist pass in blender) inside an OpenEXR file. However, I intend to have only one single channel for the same containing just the mist data inside of it.

for this, I have tried to do the following setup under the compositor window:

[image]

As can be seen through the properties of the node, I cannot see a way of creating an Open EXR file with just a single channel. I tried opening the file in python using OpenCV and getting a three-channel output.

Is this possible in blender? Can someone guide me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure to get your question. Do you need to render a single render pass or a single RGB channel?

Comment: @Emir so currently using OpenCV, I see output for example like [ 11.02,11.02,11.02]. I believe this refers to three channels like an RGB image. However, I want to get an OpenEXR file having only a single channel something like [11.02] (consisting of the mist values) instead of a 3 channel output. Something similar to what we would have in a grayscale image.

Comment: @Emir I edited the question... I see I had used the word channel and pass interchangeably... sorry for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do use one channel from an image in a material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43292/how-do-use-one-channel-from-an-image-in-a-material)

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't this require me to create an entirely new material? Can I not simply store just the values of a single pass(mist pass in my case) in an open EXR file having only one channel instead of the three that I am currently getting?